# Was "Final Destination" ever pulled off the air temporarily after 9/11?

Tags: final-destination

I know the movie came out in 2000, 1 year before the attacks.

I ask because I'm watching it and I know the first half of the movie revolves around a plane explosion so I'm wondering if 9/11 had the movie pulled out of broadcast, including even on premium networks.

Comment: It's really unfortunate this question has amassed such a load of downvotes, but I guess it might be unavoidable with such a somewhat controversial topic. I can only hope people actually downvoted it for being about 9/11, rather than for being a bad question, since it simply isn't.

Answer (score 1):

The answer: **No**

9/11 was indeed a traumatic day for almost every American, and certainly in New England (where I live) because many of us knew someone who worked in and around that area.  However, there was never a time when movies like Final Destination were pulled from the air.  Final Destination was somewhat of a B-Movie horror film that didn't have the pull of, say, Die Hard 2, which also featured a climactic scene in which a plane explodes.  Given that the explosion in Final Destination had nothing to do with terrorism, or even the methods used on 9/11, there really was no tie in to those events.

Comment: Someone on Yahoo Answers told me at least in their locality it was. Maybe it was on a local affiliate basis. Perhaps in New York City the movie was never pulled but maybe a small town in Kansas or Alabama did pull it off their affiliate

Comment: But at least what you're saying would indicate that at least on the premium networks they never got pulled off

Comment: Really I disagree that it was a B-movie. The movie was well-received although not 4-star material. And it was a box office hit